# Getting user logged in with django-social-auth

Tags: django, django-socialauth, django-users, django-login, django-unittest

I set up a unit test as such:

```
class UserViewTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.user_passwords = '123456'
        self.user1 = User.objects.create(username='Bobby Johnson', password=self.user_passwords)

    ...

    def test_view_user(self):
        """
        Check that you can view a user's information correctly in their profile
        """
        response = self.client.get(reverse('login'))
        self.assertContains(response, "You're not logged in yet", status_code=200)
        self.client.login(username=self.user1.username, password=self.user_passwords)
        response = self.client.get(reverse('login'))
        self.assertContains(response, "You've logged in already", status_code=200)
```

Only the last assertion fails, and replacing "You've logged in already" with "You're not logged in yet" in that last assertion makes the test pass, so it appears my login failed. I'm guessing this is because I'm using `django-social-auth` to allow OpenId logins.

How can I somehow get the unit tests to think that my user has logged in, so that `user.is_authenticated` is true? I just want to test that my views display correctly when a user is logged in vs otherwise, and don't particularly care about unit-testing that the login actually works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 self.user1 = User.objects.create(username='Bobby Johnson', password=self.user_passwords)
```

Should be:

```
self.user1 = User.objects.create_user(username='Bobby Johnson', password=self.user_passwords)
```

Otherwise the password is not hashed and is not usable.

---

You'll also need to have `django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend` present in your authentication backends.

---

Then,

```
self.client.login(username=self.user1.username, password=self.user_passwords)
```

will *just work*.